# Minus sign in double quotes in grep is recognized like an option

Tags: bash, grep

If I'm writing

```
grep -v "-NO" file
```

it says

> grep: invalid option -- 'N'

So I need to write `grep -v -- "-NO" file` or `grep -v "\-NO" file`.

But why it recognizes the `-` as option if it is in double quotes?

Comment: The quotes are removed by the shell before the arguments are passed to `grep`, in a step called [Quote Removal](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quote-Removal). Also see [Simple Command Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion). So, really, `grep` never sees these quotes.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I think you could post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quotes are removed by the shell before the arguments are passed to grep, in a step called [Quote Removal](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quote-Removal). Also see [Simple Command Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion). So, really, `grep` never sees these quotes.

Comment: But it's only an explanation. How to use `grep` pattern with negative signs then...

Comment: @koras: the answer to your question is given in OP: use `--` to mark the end of options, e.g., `grep -v -- "-NO" file`. Everything after the `--` will not be interpreted by `grep` as options.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm trying to grep something more complicated like `ssh -D *:10132 -N -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` for example while I'm listing processes.

Comment: @koras: to grep this command exactly you can use: `grep 'ssh -D \*:10132 -N -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'`. Just make sure that the string you want to grep is passed as single argument (hence the quotes) and that the special regex characters (here, the asterisk `*`) are properly escaped (with a backslash).

Comment: Dude. I owe you one. I was gonna kill myself here :D